Laravel Stripe unable to create checkoutsession for already existing invoice
My stack: Laravel & stripephp
Scenario: There is an open invoice which is already generated for a subscription. Stripe invoice ID (in_1PVBjnSE4D7cjIupbEfXsQ4w).
I want to achieve the following
step 1 - create an url for the customer to pay for the invoice generated.
step 2 - customer pays for invoice ID (in_1PVBjnSE4D7cjIupbEfXsQ4w).
step 3 - after payment customer should be redirected back to redirect url.
Problem: redirect is working but invoice in question is not paid. but instead a new invoice for the same amount is charged.
What I have been trying: I am trying to create a stripe session which help in redirect. but seems i am not able to direct stripe system to pay for specific invoice.
here is my controller code which generates the stripe session.
public function createCheckoutSession(Request $request, $invoiceId)
    {
        $firmId = session('firmdatas.id');
        $firmData = Firmregistration::findOrFail($firmId);

        $invoice = FirmInvoices::findOrFail($invoiceId);
        $stripeObj = new \Stripe\StripeClient(config('services.stripe.secret'));
        $subscription = $stripeObj->subscriptions->retrieve($invoice->stripe_subscription_id);
        try {
            $session = $stripeObj->checkout->sessions->create([
                'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
                'line_items' => [[
                    'price_data' => [
                        'currency' => 'usd',
                        'product_data' => [
                            'name' => 'Invoice Payment',
                        ],
                        'unit_amount' => $invoice->amount_due,
                    ],
                    'quantity' => 1,
                ]],
                'subscription_data' => [
                    'items' => [
                        ['plan' => $subscription->items->data[0]->id], // Assuming only one item in the subscription
                    ],
                ],
                'mode' => 'payment',
                'customer' => $firmData->stripe_id,
                'payment_intent_data' => [
                    'description' => "Payment for Invoice #{$invoice->number}",
                    'metadata' => [
                        'invoice_id' => $invoice->invoice_id,
                    ],
                ],
                'success_url' => route('admin.subscription.invoice.paymentsuccess', [
                    'invoiceid' => $invoice->invoice_id,
                    'amount_paid' => $invoice->amount_due, // Stripe will update the actual amount paid after payment
                    'receipt_url' => '', // Placeholder, will be updated below
                ]),
                'cancel_url' => route('admin.subscription.view'),
            ]);

            // Redirect to the Checkout Session URL
            return redirect()->away($session->url);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Error creating Stripe Checkout Session: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return view('errors.500');
        }
    }

Above I am trying to pass the subscription, or invoice id.. nothing seems to work. specific invoice is not paid.
Please advise.

Checkout Sessions are used to generate new one-time payments or Subscriptions. They can't be used for an already-created Invoice (as you noted). Instead, you would use the Invoice's Hosted Invoice Page via the hosted_invoice_url here to direct your customer to payment. However, there is no way to force a redirect to a return URL afterward when using this hosted Invoice URL. If you want that level of control then you would need to build out your own payment page using Payment Element and you would pass the desired Invoice's PaymentIntent's client_secret to your frontend to render Payment Element.

chatgpt took me out for a ride for atleast 3 hours. it never told me that it is not possible. everytime a new order gets created but existing invoice is not paid.
Any other solutions in this situation. we are not in a position to implement own payment page. we need to use stripe pages.
